# Java Recursion Advance

Tags: java, math, recursion

I am trying to write a java program which uses recursion to compute the power tower function. Your function will take as input  three values: base, power, and height. It should then compute something like (((2^2)^2)^2).
I am not getting the right computation, please tell me what is wrong.

This is what I have:

```
public double powerTower(double base, int power, int height){     

    if (base == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (power == 1) {
        return base;
    } else if(height == 1){
        return base * powerTower(base, power - 1, height - 1);
    }else if(power == 0){
        return 1;
    }else {
        return base * powerTower(base, power -1, height-1) * Math.pow(base, height*power);
        //return Math.pow(base, power*height)*base;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is height? Is it the number of times raised to 2 comes? What will be the height in the example you have given?

Comment: Do you have the brackets the right way around? I thought it would have been 2^(2^(2^2)) for a power tower?

Comment: yes muzzlator powertower

Comment: Jitin Kodian the Base is 2, Power is 4, and Height is 3

Answer (score 0):

According to math function definition, you do not need any height.
Just check correct recursion:

```
private static int powerTower(int base, int power) {
    if (power == 1) {
        return base;
    } else {
        return (int) Math.pow(base, powerTower(base, power - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that if you provide power = 5 it means that 2 to the power of 65536. It's really big number.

Comment: I do need a height

Comment: Really? For what?

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the "power tower" function is not quite clear. Here I expect that `height` can never be less than 1 and that

```
powerTower(2,3,4) = ((((2^3)^3)^3)^3)
```

i.e. `power` is replicated `height` times. I think in this case the simplest solution is to first introduce a helper funciton for just `power` and then use it to calcualte `powerTower`

```
static double power(double base, int power)
{
    if ((base == 0) || (base == 1))
    {
        return base;
    }
    else if (power == 0)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    else if (power == 1)
    {
        return base;
    }
    else
    {
        return base * power(base, power - 1);
    }
}

public static double powerTower(double base, int power, int height)
{
    if (height == 1)
    {
        return power(base, power);
    }
    else
    {
        double newBase = powerTower(base, power, height - 1);
        return power(newBase, power);
    }
}
```

P.S. actually if my understanding of the definition of power-tower is correct than

```
powerTower(base, power, height) = base^(power^height)
```

which can be implemented in a simpler way but I expect such implementation is not what is expected from you.

Answer (score -1):

check this. it will work

```
public long powerTower(long base, long power, long height){     
        for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
            base= (long) Math.pow(base,power);
        }
        return base;
}
```

Comment: Is it recursion?